# MySQL - Peak visit counts by datetime period

Tags: mysql

I have a visits table (id int, start datetime, end datetime), and I you wish to track peak visit counts.

Example data:

```
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id   | date-time-1         | date-time-2         |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1059 | 2016-07-04 19:13:00 | 2016-07-04 19:20:05 |
| 1060 | 2016-07-04 19:13:30 | 2016-07-04 19:14:25 |
| 1061 | 2016-07-04 19:14:39 | 2016-07-04 19:20:05 |
| 1062 | 2016-07-05 02:34:40 | 2016-07-05 02:45:23 |
| 1063 | 2016-07-05 02:34:49 | 2016-07-05 02:45:34 |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

The expected result should be:

```
+-------------------------------------------+-------+ 
| date-time-1         | date-time-2         | count | 
+-------------------------------------------+-------+ 
| 2016-07-04 19:13:00 | 2016-07-04 19:13:29 | 1     | 
| 2016-07-04 19:13:30 | 2016-07-04 19:14:25 | 2     | 
| 2016-07-04 19:14:26 | 2016-07-04 19:14:38 | 1     | 
| 2016-07-04 19:14:39 | 2016-07-04 19:20:05 | 2     | 
| 2016-07-04 19:20:06 | 2016-07-05 02:34:39 | 0     | 
| 2016-07-05 02:34:40 | 2016-07-05 02:34:48 | 1     | 
| 2016-07-05 02:34:49 | 2016-07-05 02:45:23 | 2     | 
| 2016-07-05 02:45:24 | 2016-07-05 02:45:34 | 1     | 
+------+------------------------------------+-------+
```

Comment: Right. I just figured out the dates were from and to times for each visit.

Comment: There should be at least one second difference from one period to another.

Comment: Lol @AshwinNair you deleted yours I deleted mine :)

Comment: Yep : ). I'll let this one be.

Comment: It's a good question...upvoting to negate unexplained, unnecessary downvote.

Comment: Since I'm doing nothing right now I will set up an answer. :)

Comment: If there are no intervals between the first row and the second as first ends with `19:13:30` and second starts with `19:13:31` your count is wrong, because for the first row there are 2 visits, for the second 2 for the third 3 and for the last one 2. So I ask, you need this interval or you will edit the counts?

Comment: @JorgeCampos the expected results are not explained and certainly don't hit minute rounded time segments. Requires the use of a Spiderman Decoder Ring. So idk I wouldn't sweat this one until pinged.

Comment: LoL @Drew I'm waiting for his answer, I've already set up a sqlfiddle with the result I mentioned.

Comment: @JorgeCampos, @AshwinNair, you're right, if there are no intervals between the first row and the second as first ends with `19:13:30` and second starts with `19:13:31` my count is wrong.

Comment: Edit your question with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not very efficient, but it'll give you your result:

```
select U.dt1 as date-time-1, DATE_ADD(U.dt2,INTERVAL -1 SECOND) as date-time-2, 
    (select count(id) from Visits where 
    (dt1 >= u.dt1 and dt1<U.dt2)  --(dt1)dt2
    or (dt1<u.dt1 and dt2>=u.dt2)   -- dt1()dt2
    --or (dt2 >= u.dt1 and dt2<U.dt2) -- dt1(dt2) (comment this line to get your result which I believe is incorrect)
    ) as count 
from (
    select A.dt1 as dt1, (
        select min(M.dt) from ( select min(dt2) as dt from Visits where dt2 > A.dt1 union select min(dt1) as dt from Visits where dt1 > A.dt1) M
    ) as dt2 from Visits A
union 
    select B.dt2 as dt1, (
        select min(M.dt) from ( select min(dt2) as dt from Visits where dt2 > b.dt2 union select min(dt1) as dt from Visits where dt1 > b.dt2) M 
    ) as dt2 from Visits b where B.dt2 <> (select max(dt2) from Visits)
) U
```

I've commented the condition checking to see if a visit starts before a range and ends within it to get the same result set as you but I believe you should consider this.

Comment: I've modified this answer.

Answer (score 0):

So to make this work you need to understand your periods and the overlapping between then. We agreed in comments that to make it work in the right way you should have from the second row on, at least one second added to the prior end. In order to understand that I will add a graph of how your periods will be and right bellow the periods from the `visits` table so you will see in the end that the times (since all periods are same day and hour, I will leave just minutes and seconds on the graph)

```
13:00        13:30         14:26      14:39
^            ^             ^          ^           
|------------||-----------||----------||-----------|
              |_ 13:31    |_ 14:25     |_ 14:40    |_ 20:05

--and in your table
13:00                                              20:05
^                                                  ^
|--------------------------------------------------|
             |------------|           14:39        20:05
             |_ 13:30     |_ 14:25    ^            ^
                                      |------------|
```

To achieve such periods table I've created a `VIEW` to facilitate the query, here is the code to it:

```
create or replace view vw_times as
  select dtstart as dt from visits
   UNION
  select dtend as dt from visits;
```

The purpose of this view is to identify all dates `starts` and `ends` of your given periods.

And here is the query that will produce such periods scenarios:

```
SELECT case when cnt>1 
           then date_add(dtstart,interval 1 second) 
           else dtstart 
           end as dtstart,
         dtend
  from (SELECT dtstart, 
               dtend, 
               @ct:=@ct+1 as cnt
          FROM ( SELECT t1.dt as dtstart,
                        (select min(x.dt) 
                           from vw_times as x
                          where x.dt > t1.dt
                         ) as dtend
                   FROM vw_times t1,
                        (select @ct := 0) as cttab
                  ORDER BY t1.dt
                ) t2
          WHERE dtend is not null
        ) as t3
```

And from it you can `LEFT JOIN` your table to find the overlapping periods like this:

```
SELECT times.dtstart, times.dtend, count(*)
  FROM (SELECT case when cnt>1 
                 then date_add(dtstart,interval 1 second) 
                 else dtstart 
                 end as dtstart,
               dtend
        from (SELECT dtstart, 
                     dtend, 
                     @ct:=@ct+1 as cnt
                FROM ( SELECT t1.dt as dtstart,
                              (select min(x.dt) 
                                 from vw_times as x
                                where x.dt > t1.dt
                               ) as dtend
                         FROM vw_times t1,
                              (select @ct := 0) as cttab
                        ORDER BY t1.dt
                      ) t2
                WHERE dtend is not null
              ) as t3
       ) as times 
       LEFT JOIN visits v 
              ON (    times.dtstart >= v.dtstart
                  AND times.dtend <= v.dtend)
 GROUP BY times.dtstart, times.dtend
```

This will result in:

```
dtstart                      dtend                   count(*)
July, 04 2016 19:13:00       July, 04 2016 19:13:30     1
July, 04 2016 19:13:31       July, 04 2016 19:14:25     2
July, 04 2016 19:14:26       July, 04 2016 19:14:39     1
July, 04 2016 19:14:40       July, 04 2016 19:20:05     2
```

See it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3509ff/10

**EDIT**

Since you added a comment with the final result, it would make the final query even smaller:

```
SELECT times.dtstart, 
       case when times.dtend = vmax.maxend
            then date_add(times.dtend, interval 1 second)
            else times.dtend
            end as dtend, 
       count(*)
  FROM  (SELECT dtstart, 
               dtend
          FROM ( SELECT t1.dt as dtstart,
                        (select min(date_sub(x.dt, interval 1 second)) 
                           from vw_times as x
                          where x.dt > t1.dt
                        ) as dtend
                   FROM vw_times t1
                  ORDER BY t1.dt
               ) t2
        WHERE t2.dtend is not null
       ) as times 
       LEFT JOIN visits as v
              ON (    times.dtstart >= v.dtstart
                  AND times.dtend <= v.dtend)
       LEFT JOIN (select max(date_sub(v.dtend, interval 1 second)) as maxend
                    from visits v) vmax
              ON ( times.dtend = vmax.maxend )
 GROUP BY times.dtstart, 
          case when times.dtend = vmax.maxend
            then date_add(times.dtend, interval 1 second)
            else times.dtend
            end
```

That will result in:

```
dtstart                   dtend                 count(*)
July, 04 2016 19:13:00    2016-07-04 19:13:29    1
July, 04 2016 19:13:30    2016-07-04 19:14:24    2
July, 04 2016 19:14:25    2016-07-04 19:14:38    1
July, 04 2016 19:14:39    2016-07-04 19:20:05    2
```

See it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3509ff/24

Comment: The query is **almost** perfect, but the final result should be: 2016-07-04 19:13:00 to 2016-07-04 19:13:29: 1, 2016-07-04 19:13:30 to 2016-07-04 19:14:25: 2, 2016-07-04 19:14:26 to 2016-07-04 19:14:38: 1, 2016-07-04 19:14:39 to 2016-07-04 19:20:05: 2

Comment: Hmm the last value have a missing second, I will edit tomorrow it is late here at my end. It willl be like the first one.

Comment: @FedericoOmoto See my last edit. I think it is ok now. Please, add the new values on the insert commands at provided sqlfiddle so you can test it. If something is still wrong let me know.

Comment: There are minimum differences between the results I get with this query and the desired results. Please see: http://pastebin.com/HhS4h36D
Thanks a lot for your efforts on this!

Comment: The query works fine for the data you presented, can you show actually the real data? You presented just those three rows with id 1059, 1060, 1061. For the result you want it must have more data than that. Show me so I can see what is wrong.

Comment: Please take a look at my edited question (EDIT). Those rows are real data from my table. Please note that I've added ids 1062 and 1063. Your query have a 1 second difference on some row results, and with the additional data (ids 1062 and 1063), there's a row with a count of 1 when it should be 0. You can see the difference of your query results versus the desired results here: http://pastebin.com/HhS4h36D
Thanks again for taking the time on looking at this!!!

Comment: In case you're unable to see my edited question with the new data, here's a pastebin with the example data (rows with id 1059, 1060, 1061, 1062 and 1063), the desired results and your query results so you can compare them: http://pastebin.com/YkASfwrb
Thanks!

Comment: You didn't understand the purpose of the query. The result set you want is impossible because you are adding data that doesn't exist into the set. The `date-time-2` can never be the same existent data of existing rows it will always be one existing data minus one second except for the last row. And the first query is always one existing data minus one second for the field `date-time-1` except for the first result. There is nothing wrong with the query. Analyze your data properly to understand the result both queries give.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see any problem on my reasoning. Your query gives almost perfect results. Please see your query here with the new two added records to the table: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fec695/2
The first difference I see is on the fifth row, the `count` value should be `0`, as there are no visits on that time range. There are also a 1 second less difference on `date-time-2` column for the second, fourth and seventh row. And at last, there are also a 1 second less difference on `date-time-1` column for the third, fifth and eight (last) row.

Comment: Just for clarity, I've edited my original question leaving only the EDITed part. Thanks!