# Can PostgreSQL LAG() function refer to itself?

Tags: postgresql

I've just discovered [LAG() function](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-lag-function/) in PostgreSQL and I've been experimenting to see what it can achieve. I've though that I might calculate factorial with it and I wrote

```
SELECT i, i * lag(factorial, 1, 1) OVER (ORDER BY i, 1) as factorial FROM generate_series(1, 10) as i;
```

But [online IDE](https://sqliteonline.com/) complains that `42703 column "factorial" does not exist`.

Is there any way I can access the result of previous LAG call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't refer to the column recursively in its definition.

However, you can express the factorial calculation as:

```
SELECT i, EXP(SUM(LN(i)) OVER w)::int factorial
FROM generate_series(1, 10) i
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY i ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW);
-- outputs:
 i  | factorial 
----+-----------
  1 |         1
  2 |         2
  3 |         6
  4 |        24
  5 |       120
  6 |       720
  7 |      5040
  8 |     40320
  9 |    362880
 10 |   3628800
(10 rows)
```

Postgresql does support an advanced SQL feature called recursive query, which can also be used to express the factorial table recursively:

```
WITH RECURSIVE series AS (
  SELECT i FROM generate_series(1, 10) i
)
, rec AS (
  SELECT i, 1 factorial FROM series WHERE i = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT series.i, series.i * rec.factorial 
  FROM series 
  JOIN rec ON series.i = rec.i + 1
)
SELECT * 
FROM rec;
```

---

**what `EXP(SUM(LN(i)) OVER w)` does:**

This exploits the mathematical identities that:

```
[1]: log(a * b * c) = log (a) + log (b) + log (c)
[2]: exp (log a) = a
[combining 1&2]: exp(log a + log b + log c) = a * b * c
```

SQL does not have an aggregate multiply operation, so to perform an aggregate multiply operation, we first have to take the log of each value, then we can use the sum aggregate function to give us the the log of the values' product. This we invert with the final exponentiation step.

This works as long as the values being multiplied are positive as `log` is undefined for 0 and negative numbers. If you have negative numbers, or zero, the trick is to check if any value is 0, then the whole aggregation is 0, and check if the number of negative values is even, then the result is positive, else it is negative. Alternatively, you could also convert the reals to the complex plane and then use the identity `Log(z) = ln(r) - iπ`

**what `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` does**

This declares an expanding window frame that includes all preceding rows, and the current row.

e.g.

```
when i equals 1 the values in this window frame are {1}
when i equals 2 the values in this window frame are {1,2}
when i equals 3 the values in this window frame are {1,2,3}
```

**what is a recursive query**

A recursive query lets you express recursive logic using SQL. Recursive queries are often used to generate parent-child relationships from relational data (think manager-report, or product classification hierarchy), but they can generally be used to query any tree like structure.

[Here is a SO answer I wrote a while back that illustrates and explains some of the capabilities of recursive queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597366/sql-query-to-get-src-to-dest-path-for-connecting-flights).

There are also a tonne of useful tutorials on recursive queries. It is a very powerful sql-language feature and solves a type of problem that are very difficult do do without recursion.

Hope this gives you more insight into what the code does. Happy learning!

Comment: wow, that is embarrassing. thanks for the catch. i somehow conflated factorial & fibonacci and came up with something that is neither. See updated answer illustrating how window frames can be used to apply formula on varying number of rows.

Comment: I can't say I understand either of these solutions but since "you can't refer to the column recursively in its definition" is technically an answer to my question, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @Presto, see updated answer. hope the explanations help your understanding of the code. happy learning