# Full History Join

Tags: sql, db2

currently I am trying to figure out a join between to historized tables, where I want to synchronize both timeline. 
As an example, I have the following two tables:

```
A
ID      Value   FROM        TO
1       5       01.01.2018  31.03.2018
1       6       31.03.2018  08.04.2018

B       A_FK    Value   FROM        TO
1       1       50      01.02.2018  01.04.2018
2       1       51      04.04.2018  10.04.2018
```

As a baseline, I want to take the timeline of table A and join table B, including NULL values so that I know, for which times there is no fitting value.
The desired result should look like this:

```
C
Value_A    Value_B   FROM        TO
5          NULL      01.01.2018  01.02.2018
5          50        01.02.2018  31.03.2018
6          50        31.03.2018  01.04.2018
6          NULL      01.04.2018  04.04.2018
6          51        04.04.2018  08.04.2018
```

Can you help me with this? I started, but can fail to align the wrong history - here my try:

```
with a as (SELECT *
 FROM (VALUES (1,5,'01.01.2018','31.03.2018')
         , (1,6,'31.03.2018','08.04.2018')
   ) A (ID, VALUE, FROM, TO)),
b as (
SELECT *
  FROM (VALUES (1,1,50,'01.02.2018','01.04.2018')
             , (2,1,51,'04.04.2018','10.04.2018')
       ) A (ID,A_FK, VALUE, FROM, TO)
)
select 
a.value as value_a,
b.value as value_b,
max(a.from,b.from) as from,
min(a.to,b.to) as to
from a
left outer join b on 
a.id = b.a_fk and
a.from < b.to and
a.to > b.from;
```

As you can see, it aligns, but not the way I expected it to.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: I've answered a question here with similar problem it may help. It is for MySQL but if you understand the technique you can apply to your problem easily. Here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38194463/460557

Comment: But shouldn't this problem be easier? The From and To of each result is already in the table, so I don't have to calculate it. I thought, some sort of join should be enough

Comment: Not quite, the main problem is that you need to create intervals that aren't in your registries. such as: `01.01.2018 - 01.02.2018` or `01.02.2018  31.03.2018`

Comment: @bublitz take a look at my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I suggested in the comments with the technique in my own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38194463/460557) from another question you can solve your problem.

Here is one solution.

The test data:

```
create table a (
  id integer,
  value integer,
  dtfrom date,
  dtto date
);

create table b(
  id integer,
  a_fk integer,
  value integer,
  dtfrom date,
  dtto date
);

insert into a values 
   (1, 5, '2018-01-01', '2018-03-31'), 
   (1, 6, '2018-03-31', '2018-04-08');
insert into b values 
   (1, 1, 50, '2018-02-01', '2018-04-01'), 
   (2, 1, 51, '2018-04-04', '2018-04-10');
```

The trick part of this solution is to generate the date intervals that isn't in any of your tables such as `01.01.2018-01.02.2018` and `01.02.2018-31.03.2018` so in order to do that you must have all available dates as one table so I created a VIEW called **timmings** to make it easier:

```
create or replace view timmings as
  select a.dtfrom dt from a inner join b on a.id=b.a_fk
  union
  select a.dtto from a inner join b on a.id=b.a_fk
  union
  select b.dtfrom from a inner join b on a.id=b.a_fk
  union
  select b.dtto from a inner join b on a.id=b.a_fk;
```

After that you need a query to generate all available periods (starts and ends) so it will be:

```
select t1.dt as start,
      (select min(t2.dt) 
         from timmings t2 
        where t2.dt>t1.dt) as dend
 from timmings t1
order by start;
```

This will result in (with your sample data):

```
  start          dend
01/01/2018    01/02/2018
01/02/2018    31/03/2018
31/03/2018    01/04/2018
01/04/2018    04/04/2018
04/04/2018    08/04/2018
08/04/2018    10/04/2018
10/04/2018    null
```

With that you can use it to get all available values from table `a` that intersects with the periods:

```
select a.id, a.value, tm.start, tm.dend
  from (select t1.dt as start,
              (select min(t2.dt) 
                 from timmings t2 
                where t2.dt>t1.dt) as dend
         from timmings t1) tm
      left join a on tm.start >= a.dtfrom and tm.dend <= a.dtto 
 where a.id is not null
 order by tm.start;
```

That results in:

```
id   value    start         end
 1     5    01/01/2018   01/02/2018
 1     5    01/02/2018   31/03/2018
 1     6    31/03/2018   01/04/2018
 1     6    01/04/2018   04/04/2018
 1     6    04/04/2018   08/04/2018
```

And finally you `LEFT JOIN` it with `b` table:

```
 select x.value as valueA,
        b.value as valueB,
        x.start as "from",
        x.dend as "to"
   from (select a.id, a.value, tm.start, tm.dend
          from (select t1.dt as start,
                      (select min(t2.dt) 
                         from timmings t2 
                        where t2.dt>t1.dt) as dend
                 from timmings t1) tm
              left join a on tm.start >= a.dtfrom and tm.dend <= a.dtto 
         where a.id is not null
        ) x 
      left join b on b.a_fk = x.id
                 and b.dtfrom <= x.start
                 and b.dtto >= x.dend
   order by x.start;
```

Which will give you the result you want:

```
valueA   valueB     start       end
 5        null   01/01/2018  01/02/2018
 5        50     01/02/2018  31/03/2018
 6        50     31/03/2018  01/04/2018
 6        null   01/04/2018  04/04/2018
 6        51     04/04/2018  08/04/2018
```

See the final solution working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36418e/1 It is MySQL but since it is all SQL ANSI it will work just fine in DB2

Comment: All end dates in the original data are pretty clearly exclusive, as they should be.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse well they are indeed, about "as they should be" is the OP's requirement to decide. And his desired result is pretty clear and it was delivered here in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent Blog article about that 
"[Fun with Date Ranges](https://www.idug.org/p/bl/et/blogaid=672)" by John Maenpaa

And secondly if you have a chance to influence the DDL I would recommend to have a closer look at Db2 Temporal Tables - they come with full SQL support (Time Travel SQL) - find details [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0058476.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually really simple if you have what's known as a Calendar table - a table with every date in it - although you can construct one on-the-fly if necessary.  You can use it to turn this more obviously into a [gaps-and-islands](/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) problem.
(You want one anyways, since they're one of the most useful analysis dimension tables):

```
SELECT valueA, valueB, 
       MIN(calendarDate) AS startDate, 
       MAX(calendarDate) + 1 DAY AS endDate
FROM (SELECT A.val AS valueA, B.val AS valueB, Calendar.calendarDate,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Calendar.calendarDate) -
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.val, B.val ORDER BY Calendar.calendarDate) AS grouping                       
      FROM Calendar
      LEFT JOIN A
             ON A.startDate <= Calendar.calendarDate
                AND A.endDate > Calendar.calendarDate
      LEFT JOIN B
             ON B.startDate <= Calendar.calendarDate
                AND B.endDate > Calendar.calendarDate
      WHERE A.val IS NOT NULL 
            OR B.val IS NOT NULL) Groups
GROUP BY valueA, valueB, grouping
ORDER BY grouping
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6511a/13/0)</kbd> (Minor tweaks for SQL Server usage in example)

...which yields the following results.  Note that there's a few extra days from the date range in table B that aren't present in table A!

```
valueA  valueB  startDate   endDate
5       (null)  2018-01-01  2018-02-01
5       50      2018-02-01  2018-03-31
6       50      2018-03-31  2018-04-01
6       (null)  2018-04-01  2018-04-04
6       51      2018-04-04  2018-04-08
(null)  51      2018-04-08  2018-04-10
```

(This of course is trivially changeable by switching the join to A to a regular `INNER JOIN`, but I figured this and other cases would be important.)